# Creating a matrix of Gaussian wavelets at dyadic scales

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I need to create a diagonal matrix containing the Fourier coefficients of the Gaussian wavelet function, but I'm unsure of what to do.

Currently, I'm using function [ConstructHaarWaveletTransformationMatrix](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33625-haar-wavelet-transformation-matrix-implementation) to generate the [Haar wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) matrix and am taking the rows at dyadic scales (2, 4, 8, and 16) as the transform:

```
M = 256
H = ConstructHaarWaveletTransformationMatrix(M);
fi = conj(dftmtx(M))/M;
H = fi*H;
H = H(4,:);
H = diag(H);
```

etc.

How do I repeat this for Gaussian wavelets? Is there a built-in [MATLAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) function which will do this for me?

For reference, I'm implementing the algorithm in section 4 of the paper in *[Compressed Sensing for Wideband Cognitive Radios](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4218361)*.

I need to do edge detection on a 1D signal, which is constructed like so:

```
edges = [50, 120, 170, 200, 220, 224, 256];
levels = [24,3,30,0,36,0,0];
idxs = zeros(1,max(edges));
idxs(edges(1:end-1)+1) = 1;
psd = levels(cumsum(idxs)+1);
```

When I just `wavdec` and the differentiation matrix:

```
[y1,y2] = wavedec(psd, 0, 'haar');
z0 = gamma*y1.';
```

I get exactly what I want.

The point, however, is that I want to recreate this edge information compressively (that is, by solving a linear program).

The fact that using the matrix above creates gibberish is my current sticking point. I want to replace it with something else and see if it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the problem was that I was working in the frequency domain, but implementing an algorithm in the time domain.

I've removed the pre-multiplications of the Fourier matrix in the time domain and everything works fine.